# Sending Email on behalf of a different username other than authenticating username

Tags: docusignapi

I have a docusign developer account in demo.docusign.net. I am integrating my application with docusign through SOAP API. I want to send signature email notification through a different username other than authenticating user. I guess my requirement is close to SOBO(Send On Behalf Of) feature in docusign. But when I am building the SOAP Header like below it is throwing an error 
Error : "This User lacks sufficient permissions. Fail to resolve SendOnBehalfOf user"

Soap Header:

```
r.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", String.Format("<DocuSignCredentials><Username>{0}</Username><Password>{1}</Password><IntegratorKey>{2}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>", "[memukesh@yahoo.com; Mka Agr]" & UserName, Password, IntegratorKey))
```

Raw XML:

```
 POST https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 2.0.50727.5420)
    X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>[memukesh@yahoo.com; Mka Agr]163ef546-49fd-487c-90a5-cbd0c40d174f</Username><Password>XXXXX</Password><IntegratorKey>TEST-54822f15-d597-40bf-a835-c5fd9241f97f</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
    VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPo59vkwnnhgJAhoiRA3V9nFwAAAAASqymGNrUZk6ydtO1QDqOu14YrRe53eBIkSLy+CUq/l4ACQAA
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    SOAPAction: "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/RequestStatus"
    Host: demo.docusign.net
    Content-Length: 378
    Expect: 100-continue
    Connection: Keep-Alive

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><RequestStatus xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0"><EnvelopeID>ba96b207-057f-4dbe-9696-b8ea28a2da7d</EnvelopeID></RequestStatus></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Can you please tell me whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With DocuSign you never need an account to sign documents and signing is always free, however, you do need a DocuSign account to Create and/or Send signature requests.  With that said, using SOBO is indeed one way of showing a different user name as the sender, but you can only use SOBO for authenticated users in the same account.

Therefore, if you want to show two different senders the best way is to create users for every unique sender you have.  Based on the account plan that you purchase you're allowed a given amount of users on that account plan.  You can create/add users manually through the Web Console or programmatically through the REST or SOAP APIs.

See here for creating new users through the [REST](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Add%20User%20to%20Account.htm) API.

See here for creating new users through the [SOAP](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Account%20Management%20Service%20API/AddMembersToAccount.htm%3FTocPath%3DAccount%2520Management%2520Service%2520API%2520Information%7CAccount%2520Management%2520Service%2520API%2520Methods%7C_____2) API.

Note that you can also create new accounts through the APIs as well though to do so you need to contact your account manager for a distributor code and password.

Comment: Now I added a new user using API to my account and trying to send request to dsapi.asmx with the following header.    X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>[newaddeduser@outlook.COM]163ef546-49fd-487c-90a5-cbd0c40d174f</Username><Password>XXX</Password><IntegratorKey>TEST-54822f15-d597-40bf-a835-c5fd9241f97f</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>, but getting the same error "This User lacks sufficient permissions. Fail to resolve SendOnBehalfOf user". Could you please check the same? If it requires anything to be enabled, could you please enable that also?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the format within  right:
`<Username>[mysoboemail@email.com]myconnectingemail@email.com</Username>` (or use userid instead of email).
I think you just need to change `[memukesh@yahoo.com; Mka Agr]` to only be `[memukesh@yahoo.com]`.  Remember that email has to be associated with a DocuSign account as well

Comment: You mean "memukesh@yahoo.com" has to be a docusign user as well? But my requirement is that operating user email(e.g. memukesh@yahoo.com) can be any email not necessarily a docusign email user and it will be set programatically. I will have only authenticating docusign user email. Do you have any other way if not SOBO?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure a SOBO is only from an account that exists.  You can set separate replyName and replyEmailAddress values if that helps at all.

Comment: This is my requirement. Suppose "IFS" has a client account(docuadmin@ifs.com) and if John is sending the invitation, I want john@IFS.com (John Murray) to show up in the sender information and if Jim Carter is sending an invitation, I need jim@IFS.com (Jim Carter) to show up in sender info. 
1. Ideally, I do not want to create docusign account for  john@IFS.com or jim@IFS.com
2. If I have to create docusign account for  john@IFS.com or jim@IFS.com then is it possible to do it programatically?

Could you please let me know if its possible through SOAP API integration?